# Unable to run babel-node on Windows

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, babeljs

I would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what is causing the error mentioned below.

I have a test Express project with a `scripts` section in `package.json` that looks like the following:

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "backpack",
   "build": "backpack build",
   "test-server": "babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha",
   "test-server-ms": "babel-node.cmd node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul.cmd cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha.cmd"
},
```

The `test-server-ms` script is what I am trying to execute:

```
babel-node.cmd node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul.cmd cover 
      node_modules/.bin/_mocha.cmd "test/server"
```

This yields an error when parsing the `babel-istanbul.cmd` file:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\hqrsingh\Development\workspaces\vscode\express-es6-starter\node_modules\babel
-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hqrsingh\Development\workspaces\vscode\express-es6-starter\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:154:22)
```

The error occurs when the `@IF` directive is encountered which is part of a Windows `.cmd` script in `node_modules\.bin\babel-istanbul.cmd`:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\babel-istanbul\lib\cli.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\babel-istanbul\lib\cli.js" %*
)
```

I am kicking all of this off within a Windows 7 Pro command shell via `npm`:

```
 npm run-script test-server-ms test/server
```

For reference, here is the entire `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "express-es6-starter",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "A complete boilerplate for Express.js development including unit test and code coverage.",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "backpack",
    "build": "backpack build",
    "test-server": "babel-node node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha",
    "test-server-ms": "babel-node.cmd node_modules/.bin/babel-istanbul.cmd cover node_modules/.bin/_mocha.cmd"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "test-server"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-istanbul": "^0.12.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "backpack-core": "^0.0.7",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I was able to solve this by avoiding the use of the `babel-*` modules entirely. I still do not know how one would go about executing platform specific scripts via `npm` or if that should even be encouraged.

Here is my entire `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "express-es6-starter",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "A complete boilerplate for Express.js development including unit test and code coverage.",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./build/main.js",
    "clean-build": "rm -rf ./build/*",
    "dev": "backpack dev",
    "build": "backpack build",
    "compile": "babel --presets es2015,stage-0 -d build/ src/",
    "test-client-karma": "node ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js || exit 0",
    "test-client-mocha": "mocha test/client/*.js --require babel-register --reporter spec || exit 0",
    "test-server": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test/server/**/*.js",
    "test": "npm run-script test-server; npm run-script test-client-mocha"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "test-server"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "backpack-core": "^0.0.7",
    "brfs": "^1.4.3",
    "browserify": "^14.3.0",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.14",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.2",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7", 
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

This is the project structure that the above `package.json` is based upon:

[image: Project Structure]